# Search first row for a value then get the full column range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search the first row for different values then use the column range in a formula.

In my VBA I have a formula like;

```
=INDEX('Othersheet'!$J:$J,MATCH($C5,'Othersheet'!$E:$E,0))
```

This worked fine until someone added columns to 'Othersheet'. So I thought I'd just search for the header I need and use the column it returns, but I can't work out how to do this.

Something like;

```
Range("1:1").Find("TEXT").Entirecolumn.Select
```

But that will select the column and what I need is to use the column range so I can replace the "'Othersheet'!$J:$J" with this column if it's now not in J:J.

Comment: `.Address` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
address = Sheets("Othersheet").Columns(WorksheetFunction.Match("TEXT", Range("'Othersheet'!1:1"), 0)).Address(, , , True)
```

To explain a bit, it finds the heading match from "1:1" as the question recommended, and then locate the reference of the exact column, and output the address with External flag set to True.

Comment: Using this, playing with this (removing the parts after .address), I've got a much better understanding here now. Thank you.